# Finding multiple file extensions in command prompt window

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am trying to use multiple parameters to find 3 different extensions in my windows/system32 in one command: `.exe`, `.dll` and `.sys`

This is giving me what I want, but I can't figure out how to get all 3 extensions in a single command:

`dir c:\windows\system32\*.dll /p`

Answer (score 17):

This will do it in a single command:

> dir /p c:\windows\system32\*.exe c:\windows\system32\*.dll c:\windows\system32\*.sys

A lot of people dont realize that you can have multiple sources in the dir command

Comment: After reading http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157299/8763 I got curious if I could ever do the same thing on Windows batch files.

Comment: How do you ignore the extension when sorting alphabetically?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean listing files that have one of three extensions, you should start with:

```
dir *.exe *.dll *.sys
```

Comment: I have to find all files with those 3 extensions with a pause between screens /p   all in one command prompt

Comment: FWIW, "dir c:\windows\system32\\*.dll c:\windows\system32\\*.exe c:\windows\system32\\*.sys /p" works on Windows 7

Comment: `dir *.exe *.dll *.sys /s /p`  will search all subdirectories with a pause in between each screen

Comment: After reading http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157299/8763 I got curious if I could ever do the same thing on Windows batch files.

Answer (score 1):

make this a batch file (.bat) and run it from the command prompt

```
@echo off

dir c:\windows\system32\*.dll
pause
dir c:\windows\system32\*.exe
pause
dir c:\windows\system32\*.sys
```

Comment: I upvoted, not sure if a batch file satisfies his requirement though.  My answer would definitely work

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to **C**hange **D**irectory `&&` then do the lookup

```
cd c:\windows\system32 && dir *.exe *.dll *.sys
```

Saves a bit of typing...

Answer (score 0):

To open multiple files with the same extension using the for loop
for /R %i in (*.html) do start %i

The /R switch of the for loop in batch is used to loop through directories. You can use it with a file path or without one. When used without a file path, it assumes the current directory and searches with depth. You can use the command for /? to read about other use cases.