# Search multiples file extensions on Windows drive

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, search

I am currently going throught the process of moving all my documents to a server.

I cut-paste everything I could think. Hence. I want do check my C drive for any files that might still be there and that I forgot about.

Therefore I would like to do a search on multiple extensions. For exemple I like to ask windows :

Show me all the files that have one of the following extension : .FLV .MKV .OGG. MOV .AVI .MP4 ...

Note : I am under windows 7

Currently I a searching those extension one by one but isn't there a way to go throught it all at once ?

Hope I made myself clear. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding multiple file extensions in command prompt window](http://superuser.com/questions/201300/finding-multiple-file-extensions-in-command-prompt-window)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [FileSeek](http://www.fileseek.ca/). In the `"Include Files"` field, you can enter multiple extensions like so:

```
*.flv|*.mkv|*.ogg|*.mov|*.avi|*.mp4
```

Disclosure: I work for Binary Fortress, makers of FileSeek, which is why I suggested it. There are of course, other similar applications that will allow you to search multiple file extensions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows search box you should be able to type something like:

```
ext:FLV OR ext:MKV OR ext:OGG OR ext:MOV OR ext:AVI OR ext:MP4
```

or even:

```
*.FLV OR *.MKV OR *.OGG OR *.MOV OR *.AVI OR *.MP4
```